# ¿Se puede realizar una consulta SQL Oracle que cumpla dos tareas?

Tags: sql, oracle

primero que todo explicar que es la primera vez que pregunto en StackOverflow y no sé mucho de SQL ni oracle.
Pongo contexto, tengo una tabla de la siguiente forma

[image: Tabla_Personas]

Bueno, resulta que tengo de dato de entrada el nombre de la persona, pero necesito listar todas las personas que tengan el mismo color de pelo que esta.

Mi pregunta es, ¿Puedo realizar la búsqueda en una sola query o debo buscar primero el color de pelo de la persona y luego realizar otra búsqueda que liste a todas las personas con ese color de pelo?

Gracias de antemano, Saludos :)

Comment: por favor, mira el [tour] para que sepas como funcionamos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si se puede, y es básicamente como lo has planteado: debes conocer el color de pelo de la persona que buscas y luego buscar todas aquellas que tengan este color. Esto se logra con una consulta que se la suele conocer como `semi join`, y se resuelve así:

```
select  *
    from Tabla_personas
    where Color_Pelo = (select Color_Pelo from Tabla_Personas where Nombre_Persona = 'Carlos')
```

**Importante:**

Esto `Color_Pelo = (select Color_Pelo from Tabla_Personas where Nombre_Persona = 'Carlos')` solo funciona si únicamente tenemos un solo `Carlos` en la tabla de personas, sino no fuera el caso y lo que se desea es obtener todas las personas que tengan el mismo color de pelo de cualquier `Carlos`, la consulta es ligeramente distinta

```
select  *
    from Tabla_personas
    where Color_Pelo in (select Color_Pelo from Tabla_Personas where Nombre_Persona = 'Carlos')
```

Comment: Ohh, entiendo. Muchas gracias, queda super claro :D